# Why does my color printer only print in black on one computer but print in color for the rest?

Tags: printer, colors, network-printer

Our home network has an HP Laserjet 200 color m251nw printer installed that had been working just fine for all machines on the network. But now one machine (A) will not print color although other machines (B, C) can still print color. This suggests it's local to the A machine. I've rebooted the A machine and rebooted the printer, with no improvement.

I have logged onto A as a different admin user and it still won't print color, suggesting it's not a CurrentUser setting. I have also verified that it won't print color from several different apps, e.g Word and Chrome.

If it's not user level or app level, it seems it must be machine level. Does anyone know of a machine level setting that may have gotten inserted or changed to produce this behavior?

Thank you for any ideas or assistance.

Comment: In the printer Properties. Look for something like this: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-9DBFqskF-Lk/VrLCX8UH1BI/AAAAAAAAFtY/5MZ5-V_9bvs/s1600/grayscale%2Bprinting%2B4.jpg it probably somehow get set to black only or grayscale.

Comment: @Sickest, consider signing up for a free imgur account.  That will take care of the risk of images disappearing.  If you don't want to bother with an imgur account, here's a trick to store the images here.  Open a Your Answer window and use the image icon in the editor to upload the image.  Then copy and paste the resulting link into the comment, and discard the "answer".  :-)  BTW, I can't think of any other explanation for what the OP's problem could be.  Post that as an answer, because it is likely to help someone even if it turns out not to be the solution in this case.

Comment: @fixer1234 What I was planning on doing, was after he confirmed it worked. Was to make an answer out of it and deleting my comment. I usually do post images on imgur If i can remember to do so.

Comment: I don’t know why this would have broken, if things were working find and ‘‘nothing changed’’, but this sounds like a driver problem.

Comment: Is this printer shared from one of the PCs, or does each PC print direct to the printer's IP address? If the latter, that PC could have the wrong driver installed. If the former, could there be 2 instances of the printer (one mono, one colour) on the sharing PC?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. Thank you all for your suggestions. My son was able to fix it. In his words:

Basically, I removed the printer and the 'print to Microsoft PDF' devices. The print to PDF option was showing driver errors. Then I rebooted, and added back the printer. Last, I checked the box below the devices (in the Printers and Scanners sub-menu of settings) which says 'Let Windows manage my default printer.' The two test pages I printed before and after showed very different data and the problem was fixed!